# Apple Mach-O Linker Error on Xcode 8 when using CocoaPods and Git

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, cocoapods

I've had this happen to me twice in the last few months. The solution is obvious and easy, but took me a while to remember since all the current S.O. questions and solutions I found on the error didn't work. Hopefully, the title will help others target the specific situation I have. At the very least, it will remind me what do when the error occurs again!

If you recently added a new Library (via CocoaPods or manually), and switched to another branch that does not have it, you will get the following error:

> Error #1: Apple Mach-O Linker Error: Linker command failed with exit
>   code ... linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

**What is happening**

I never `git commit` my installed CocoaPods; just the Podfile. So, when I change branches the installed Pods dir is out of sync with the podfile.

**The Solution**

Simple re-run `pod install` or `bundle exec pod install` command. Clean the project, and run it again.

**Update**

*Lesson No. 2*:

Sometimes you may forget that you removed a framework file or did not check it in. This will also cause a linker flag problem when cloning else where or checking out a new branch. Check your frameworks folder for any red text as a clue.

Most importantly, right click on your linker flag error and "show logs". This may give you a clue as to what part of your project is creating the linker issue.